# Table row clickable using anchor element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clickable

I have a nodes table with 6 columns. 
On the first column (named "Node id"), there is the index number for each node (each one on a different row). When I click on a specific index number, a modal window opens, containing the node's info.

When I created the table, I've made each node id an anchor element:

```
 if (key[j] == "nodeid") {
     var cell = document.createElement("td");
     var aux = document.createElement("a");
```

Then, when a click a particular one, I call a function that gets the node's info from a server:

```
 $("a").click(function(test) {
            getEndpoints(test.target.innerHTML);//innerHTML= node id number
        });
```

What I want to do, is to click anywhere on the row in order to open that modal window containing the information for the node displayed on that row.

What I've tried so far is to make every `<td>` and anchor element by redefining the if statement:

```
if (key[j]) {
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    var aux = document.createElement("a");

    cell.appendChild(aux);
    var cellText = document.createTextNode(value[key[j]]);
    aux.appendChild(cellText);
    row.appendChild(cell);
```

The thing is, in order for this to work correct, I always have to click on the node index first in order to get the info. If I click anywhere else on the row first, the content i get is blank.

///LATER EDIT
Here is the  getEndpoints function I use in order to get data for a particular node:

```
function getEndpoints(nodeid) {
    $.get(".../iot/cmd/node/" + nodeid + "/class/mib/act/allS", function (node) {
        window.data = node;
        var key = ["epid", "clslist", "loc", "type", "zplus"];
        var endpoints = node.endpoints[0];
        for (var k = 0; k < key.length; k++) {
            $("#" + key[k]).text(endpoints[key[k]]);
        }
    });
}
```

Then I populate this div with the data requested from getEndpoints:

```
<div id="endDiv" style="display: none">
    <ol class="rounded-list">
        <li><label>ID: <span id="name"></span></label></li>
        <li><label>LOC. NAME: <span id="loc"></span></label></li>
        <li><label>EPID: <span id="epid"></span></label></li>
        <li><label>CLSLIST: <span id="clslist"></span></label></li>
        <li><label>TYPE: <span id="type"></span> </label></li>
        <li><label>ZPLUS: <span id="zplus"></span> </label></li>

    </ol>
</div>
```

Then I put the div content in the modal window:

```
 $("a").on( "click", function() {
        $("#endDiv").contents().appendTo(".modal-content")
    });
```

Comment: Change `$('a').click(...` to `$('tr').click(...`. If that doesn't work for you, please add a more complete example of your code, including the HTML.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've tried it but doesn't work. I get a 502Bad Gateway error in console.

Comment: That means that changing the element you hook the event to has affected the data you're sending in the AJAX request. Without seeing more of your code it's impossible to tell you why that is happening

Comment: @mecnism you'd also have to alter more of your code so that `test.target.innerHTML` is still a valid URL. In other words you have to get the correct text from the table row. jQuery's "find" function would probably make that quite easy.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've edited my post and added more code. The reason for 502 error is because if I don't click first on the node index, the getEndpoints function (that has a "nodeid" parameter)  sends an incorrect AJAX request

Comment: @mecnism yes, the reason for that is because now you're selecting the tr instead of the a, then test.target.innerHTML no longer refers to the same text - before it was the text inside the anchor element, now it's the entire content of the row...you need to alter it to make it get the text from the relevant anchor within the row. See http://api.jquery.com/find/ for a hint

Comment: @ADyson thanks for the advice. I got it. What I did, is use:  getEndpoints( $(test.currentTarget).find(".nodeid")[0].innerHTML); Now I can click on any td, modal window pops out just fine